# How to stop mana increase and hp increase when rebirths=1

Tags: javascript, html

I had this easily working in python http://prntscr.com/ns14y9  but im having the hardest time replicating it on javascript. I want my hp and mana to increase only after the first rebirth buy.

I have tried doing a if statement but it doesn't seem to work at all or im formatting it incorrectly.

Here is my Javascript:

```
var rebirths = 0;
var HitPoints = 0;
var ManaPoints = 0;   

 function buyRebirth() {
    var rebirthCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
    if (cookies >= rebirthCost) {
        cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
        document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
        document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
```

Here is my html:

```
   </style>
                <span id="cookies">0</span>
                <br />
                <span id="rebirths">0</span>
                <br />
                <button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
                <br />
                Cost: 50 <button id="BigClickBtn" 
onclick="cookieClick(50)">BigClick</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span> <button 
id="cursorCostBtn" onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="catCost">50</span> <button 
onclick="buyCat()" id="catCostBtn">Buy Cat</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="dogCost">100</span> <button 
onclick="buyDog()" id="dogCostBtn">Buy Dog</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="humanCost">200</span> <button 
onclick="buyHuman()" id="humanCostBtn">Buy Human</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">10</span> <button 
onclick="buyRebirth()" id="rebirthCostBtn">Rebirth</button>
                <br />
                Hp:<span id="HitPoints">0</span> Mp:<span 
id="ManaPoints">0</span> 

                <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
            </body>
```

I expect Hp and Mp to stop increasing after rebirths > 1 . but the actual output the Hp and Mp keeps going up by 10 every time i buy rebirth.

Comment: You are not checking your `rebirth` variable anywhere.

Comment: i said i tried a if statement it didn't do anything. what's the point of a "what did you try section" if I just get suggested it in the comments. i don't know how to format it to work. how do if statements work in javascript. i posted this question to ask how to make my function stop working when rebirth > 1. I know about if statements but im new to javascript i dont know how to format it . http://prntscr.com/ns1fwh

Comment: i removed it because it didn't do anything. I wanted a working way to stop the increase in Mana and hp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't post the full definition for the `buyRebirth()` function but apparently you aren't checking if there are more than one rebirths before you increase **HitPoints** and **ManaPoints** by 10.

```
HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
```

Wrap it inside a simple if-condition:

```
if (rebirths == 0) {
  HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
  ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
}
  rebirths = rebirths + 1;
```

The next time you enter **buyRebirth**, the value of rebirths will be greater than 0 so the condition rebirths==0 will evaluate to false.

Comment: o wow ty that worked. i also found out how to do multiple if statements http://prntscr.com/ns2ajf  but your solution is a bit neater